# Is the direction in the queue matter?

Tags: data-structures, queue

Queue Is described as enqueued items added to the back/tail and dequeued items removed from the front/head

What about if I did the opposite
Add from the first (Add first) and remove from the tail (remove last)

Is it still a queue or do I have to stick with the first one?

Comment: It is still a queue. You can choose.

Comment: You are thinking about it backwards.  For a queue, "front' or "head" is what we *call* the end that you remove items from, while "tail" or "back" is what we call the end that you add items to.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.